# Cохранение qscene без потери качества

Tags: qt

Формирую монохромные изображения формата QImage::`Format_Mono (1-bit per pixel)`. Затем мне необходимо их определенным образом объединить, для чего создаю сцену и добавляю их туда. Как затем мне сохранить полученную сцену в формат .tiff  так, чтобы качество изображений осталось прежним уже будучи в таком, объединенном виде?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите скопировать "пиксель в пиксель" то, что видит пользователь в `QGraphicsView`, вы делаете:

```
QPixmap pixMap = this->ui->graphicsView->grab();
pixMap.save(fileName);
```

Если вы просто хотите отрисовать картинку со сцены:

```
QImage image(fn);
QPainter painter(&image);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
scene.render(&painter);
image.save("file_name.png")
```

Второй вариант более предпочтителен, так как он позволяет сохранить отмасштабированную сцену.

Код взят [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451183/how-to-create-image-file-from-qgraphicsscene-qgraphicsview)

Comment: я спрашивал про качество потому, что изображения, формируемые мной, имеют размерность 7100 х 7100 пикселей с размером пикселя 0.00635 мм. разве при переносе на сцену это качество не потеряется?

Comment: @jesuscrew77 если вы так сильно сомневаетесь - сравните.